# Aplicar uma função em cada elemento de uma matriz em python

Tags: python-3.x, funções, matriz, expressões-lambda, numpy

Estou precisando aplicar uma uma função lambda em todos os elementos de uma matriz em e que ele retorne uma matriz de mesma dimenção tipo assim:

eu tenho a matriz mat no estilo numpy:

```
mat = array[[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6]]
```

e a seguinte função lambda:

```
soma3 = lambda x: x + 3
```

aí eu aplico essa função na matriz e ela retornar a seguinte matriz:

```
array[[4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]]
```

desde já agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso que você deseja, utilizando o NumPy, você pode fazer uso do `vectorize`:

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])

soma3 = lambda x: x + 3

vectorize = np.vectorize(soma3)

print(vectorize(mat))
```

> https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

---

Existem outras formas de fazer isso mesmo sem a utilização do NumPy, como por exemplo, criando uma *lambda* que faça um `for` em sua lista:

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]

soma3 = lambda x: [y + 3 for y in x]

mat = list(map(soma3, mat))

print(mat)
```

Você também pode criar uma *lambda* dentro de outra:

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]

soma3 = lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y + 3, x))

mat = list(map(soma3, mat))

print(mat)
```

E por fim, você pode até mesmo criar uma *lambda* que chame uma função sua:

```
def somar3(lista):
  for index, item in enumerate(lista):
    lista[index] = item + 3

  return lista

mat = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]

soma3 = lambda x: somar3(x)

mat = list(map(soma3, mat))

print(mat)
```

Comment: No último exemplo, acho meio "exagero" usar um *lambda* que só chama a função, dá pra passar a função direto: `mat = list(map(somar3, mat))` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer apenas aplicar operações matemáticas em todos os elementos do seu `array` é muito mais fácil você simplesmente somar o número que você quer ao seu array:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6]])

print(array + 3)
# [[4 5 6]
#  [7 8 9]]
```

<sup>*Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-422353-6333)*</sup>

Você pode verificar no sessão *"quickstart tutorials"* da [documentação do Numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations) onde diz:

> Arithmetic operators on arrays apply elementwise. A new array is created and filled with the result.

Tradução livre:

> Operadores aritméticos são aplicados a cada elementos do array. Um novo array é criado e preenchido com o resultado.

Se você precisar de alguma operação mais complexa no seu `array` talvez `vectorize` seja melhor para o seu caso, mas vale lembrar que na sua [documentação](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy.vectorize) há uma nota onde diz:

> The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Tradução livre:

> A função `vectorize` é fornecida principalmente por conveniência, não por performance. A implementação é essencialmente um *for loop*.